# Find pair of customers(CustID), who have bought same number of items.(SQL Nested Query)

Tags: sql

- Invoice (InvoiceNo, CustID, OutletID, Date) PK(InvoiceNO)
- InvoiceItems (InvoiceNo, ItemID, Quantity, Discount) PK(InvoiceNO,ItemID)

PLz tell me solution of Above mention Query using nested Method Using these Two tables structure.
I am unable to solve it.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, an appropriate database tag, and your attempt to answer the question.

Comment: I am unable to post image becuase They told me to have min 10 reputations to post image...So I have unable to post sample data image

Comment: You can still post sample of tables and expected result in text ;)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
Select i1.CustID, i2.CustID
From
    (Select InvoiceNo,count(*) as nb
         From InvoiceItems
         Group by InvoiceNo) as a,
    (Select InvoiceNo,count(*) as nb
         From InvoiceItems
         Group by InvoiceNo) as b,
    Invoice as i1,
    Invoice as i2
Where a.InvoiceNo = i1.InvoiceNo
    and b.InvoiceNo = i2.InvoiceNo
    and a.InvoiceNo < b.InvoiceNo
    and a.nb = b.nb;
```

Comment: I mean same number of items* not their quantity

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: I've always been told not to use JOIN for performance reasons (so that query optimizer was able to fully do its job)

Comment: Use I think this problem can solve more easily by joins....but the problem is still unsolved...Because I am unable to join them correctly..

Comment: @txemsukr, which dbms has that problem?!? (Sounds like a 1900's problem.)

Comment: @jarlh that's what i've been told and what I learnt during my IT engineering school. I've been told that JOIN may force the query builder to build the query in a way that it is not optimized.

Comment: @Hammad I've edited my answer, is it ok for you now?

Comment: @txemsukr, forget about that recommendation. It was _perhaps_ correct many years ago, but definitely not today.

Comment: Ok thank you then, I will try to change my habits :p

Comment: @txemsukr Thank you very much you save my a lot of time...This works magically